# get name of json

Tags: javascript, jquery, json, json.net, getjson

**JSON**

product82127600211="a"

product82127600212="b"

product82127600213="c"

**javascript**

```
var idCompany=8212760021;
var idProduct="product"+idCompany+"1";
alert(products.idProduct); // this line show undefined
```

this alert show undefined but if use
   `alert(products.product82127600211);` show `a` success.

now how can create idProduct that show `a`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your syntax is wrong, use brackets instead:

```
alert(products[idProduct]);
```

Currently you are trying to access a variable named `idProduct`, i.e. your example would be equivalent to:

```
alert(products["idProduct"]);
```

Comment: yes this is right tanks. plz write more info about this for me.what reason

Answer (score 1):

```
alert(products[idProduct]); // this line show a
```

Comment: yes this is right tanks. plz write more info about this for me.what reason

Comment: @myname1234: Because that's the way you can access objects in JavaScript if you want to access them dynamically.

Answer (score 0):

Would

```
alert(products[idProduct]);
```

not work?

Comment: yes this is right tanks. plz write more info about this for me.what reason

Answer (score 0):

try

```
alert(products[idProduct]);
```

Comment: yes this is right tanks. plz write more info about this for me.what reason

Answer (score 0):

To use a variable key for an JavaScript object, use the bracket notation (`["key"]`) instead of the dot notation (`.key`). In your example you would:

```
alert(products[idProduct])
```

Comment: yes this is right tanks. plz write more info about this for me.what reason

Answer (score 0):

I believe your problem is that the reference to idProduct is not attached to your object products.

e.g.

```
products = {};
products.idProduct="product"+idCompany+"1";
alert(products.idProduct);
```

The alert shows the value of idProduct